# C (TI ARM compiler) statement is unreachable

Tags: c

I experience strange behavior of my ARM compiler in Code Composer Studio:

When neither DEFINE1 nor DEFINE2 are defined the compiler reports unreachable code:

```
#if defined(DEFINE1) || defined(DEFINE2)
  statement;  //reports warning #112-D: statement is unreachable
#endif
```

When I just write:

```
#ifdef DEFINE1
  statement;
#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef DEFINE2
  statement;
#endif
```

Then no such warning is issued.

Is that a compiler bug?

EDIT: There was my bug in code.
I used wrong symbols for DEFINE1 and DEFINE2.
Eg. for DEFINE1:
There should be

```
#undef DEFINE1
```

but there was sth. completely different:

```
#define DEFINE1 0x01
```

I just mixed two preprocessor symbols in my code.

Comment: We cannot tell if you don't show your real code. Also give the version of your compiler (which is probably some variant of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), in which case you probably should trust it). Code Composer Studio is probably an IDE, not a compiler

Comment: There's not enough context here.  I suggest looking at the preprocessed output in each case.  The statement would seem to be present in the first case, but not in either of the others, which doesn't make sense.  Have you tried it with gcc?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch and Tom: I don't think this can be answered in terms of GCC. The fact that the compiler says anything about the first case indicates that it's looking through the preprocessor to make some special diagnostics. Either it's not GCC at all, or it's augmented with some extra analysis.

Comment: Sorry was my fault, used wrong DEFINE1 and DEFINE2.

Comment: My biased intuition is that GCC is practically reliable enough to be trusted when it is giving some *statement unreachable* warning. But I also know that GCC might give wrong warnings sometime.

Comment: @tk_ you should delete your question

Comment: Unrelated: GCC defaults to settings undefined preprocessor symbols to 0, so it's a better check to say `#if defined(X) && (X == 1)`. Or you can use `-Wundef`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html

Comment: @Basile: I think it might be useful for somebody in future who makes similar bug in his code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No bugs. The compiler is telling you that you have generated **dead code**, which is code that will never be executed (unreachable), and for this reason will not be created.
From the conditions you imposed if neither of symbols is defined the code is not created.
Compilers normally silently remove dead code unless the warning level is very high (i.e. --Wpedantic or the like).